# Delete Image uploaded unsigned from client side from cloudinary

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cloudinary

I am new to cloudinary and I need to delete the image uploaded by client side web app(angularjs), but cloudinary doesn't allow delete token to return as a part of response body because of unsigned upload is there any way I can delete the image without delete token? I am not having server in between client side and cloudinary. Currently uploading the image in this code:

```
Upload.upload({
   method: "POST",
    skipAuthorization: true,

    url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + cloudinary.config().cloud_name + "/upload",
        data: {
           upload_preset: cloudinary.config().upload_preset,
           tags: '',
           file: file,
           context: 'photo=' + title,
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the upload-preset edit page (on your account [upload settings page](https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/upload)), click on the "Advanced Options" button and set "Return delete token" to "YES".
This will tell Cloudinary to include return the delete-token within the response JSON, which then can be utilized to remove the uploaded image in an unsigned manner (notice the token is only valid for 10 minutes).
More information here: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521132-How-to-delete-an-image-from-the-client-side-

Comment: there is no option in this page named advance option

Comment: @AashirJaved Did you go to the **edit page** of your specific upload-preset?

Comment: yes , my upload-preset is set to unsigned is that a reason am not seeing this option.

Comment: @AashirJaved it supposed to be there, I'll be happy to help further if you can share the cloud-name of your account. Alternatively you can open a [support ticket with Cloudinary](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)